# Octave installation error on Windows 10

Tags: file, windows-10, octave, failed-installation

I tried installing one of the three versions of Octave i.e. 4.0.0 , 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 on **Windows 10** but on all three installations, first the installation starts and then in the later stages it terminates itself converting the the setup file of octave into a **.vir fie**. Later when I rename it and try again it shows the message **Windows cannot find " path of the fie". Make sure you have typed the name correctly and try again.**

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: How do I install octave? If error like this pops up.

Comment: Where have you downloaded the installer? ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/ ist the correct source. Sound like you have a virus scanner which renames the file?

Comment: Yes I downloaded from the same source. In fact to be more specific http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/ . Yes I do have an antivirus program so I disabled it temporarily and then it doesn't convert the installer file into a .vir file but it gives the above mentioned error message.